# time complexity and space complexity dfa

Tags: math, time-complexity, computation-theory, dfa, space-complexity

So I just got this question in a problem set and I am really struggling to find an answer anywhere for this:

Let TIME(L) be the time complexity of a language and SPACE(L) be the space complexity of the same language. Show that if SPACE(L) = TIME(L)+1 the language can be decided by a DFA.

Comment: I don't think that this statement is true. DFAs can only decide languages with SPACE(L)=O(1). If TIME(L)=O(n) and SPACE(L)=O(n), then, according to the statement, the language can be decided by a DFA. But this is false.

Comment: @NicoSchertler I think what you are saying is true and thats how you can prove this true. I believe that the +1 is one level of complexity so in other words space complexity of the language is one level lower than the time complexity. Which is exactly what you said with DFA's can only decide languages with SPACE(L) = O(1). So does the time complexity of L have to be O(n)? what if SPACE(L) = O(n) and TIME(L) = O(n^2)? How would you write out the proof for your statement?

Comment: I doubt that this is what's meant by the `+1`. But the proof would be exactly the same as before.

Comment: @NicoSchertler If I remember correctly, TIME(O(n)) is precisely the class of regular languages. Choosing something like TIME(2^n) and SPACE(2^n + 1) should do the trick.